# Tag appropriate to order of growth question

Tags: discussion, tagging

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146760/what-is-the-upper-bound-on-tn-3tn-2-n) has originally been tagged "bounded variation", which is clearly wrong. I was looking for an "order of growth" tag or something similar, and couldn't find one. Three questions: what is the right tag for this question? Is there an order of growth tag? Would it be helpful to have one?

To the last question, I would suggest that there is a class of question which picks the order of growth of a function as a particular feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an "asymptotics" tag already in use. I think it would be an appropriate tag for the question to which you refer.